# Azure WordPress App Service Webp Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, azure-web-app-service, webp

I've created a new WordPress App Service.  The version of WordPress is 6.2.2 and the version of php is 8.2.5  This version of WordPress supports webp and the mime types are configured.  However when I try to add a webp image to the Media library I get an error:

This image cannot be processed by the web server. Convert it to JPEG or PNG before uploading.

After some searching, I found that web is not support by php install:

[image]

This seems to be a common problem, however I've been unable to find a solution.  Is there any way to enable webp?

Comment: Do you have `web.config` in your deployed Azure App Service?

Comment: It’s a Linux os, so I don’t think the web.config file will have any affect? The nginx config has webp mime mappings

Comment: Refer this [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/942878/azure-linux-web-app-service-enable-webp-image-supp) which explains the same issue.

Comment: @Harshitha I've seen the article and tried it, however apt-get doesn't work. After your comment, I took another look. Seems like Alpine in the distro, which uses apk. I updated the command:
apk update
apk add --no-cache build-base
apk add --no-cache --update --virtual buildDeps autoconf
apk add --no-cache freetype-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libwebp-dev libpng-dev
docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-webp --with-jpeg --with-freetype
docker-php-ext-install gd
However it still doesn't work - looks like the startup script doesn't run...

Comment: Iam able to upload images with `.webp` extension.Will post the answer in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This image cannot be processed by the web server. Convert it to JPEG or PNG before uploading.

Initially even I got the same error when tried to upload an image with `.webp` extension.

[image]

- Installed the plugins related to Webp and tried to upload, none of them helped.

***Plugins:***
[image]

- Instead of `multi-file uploader` I have tried with `browser-uploader`.

[image]

***browser-uploader:***

[image]

- Now Iam able to upload an image with `.webp` extension.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- But the problem with this approach is, you can upload a single file at a time.

Another approach can be done by adding the `webp` extension type in `web.config` file.

- We have an option to check the deployed files in Azure Linux App Service as well.

***KUDU Path for Azure Linux App Service:***

```cs
https://YourWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui
```

- You can see the deployed files in `home/site/wwwroot` folder.

[image]

- Create a new `web.config` file and follow the below link for next steps.

Thanks @DAVE CALLAN for the explanation.

Refer [Adding WebP support to Azure App Services](https://davecallan.com/adding-webp-support-to-azure-app-services/) ,to work with `web.config` file and enable `Webp` in `Azure Linux App service`.

Comment: This is an awesome answer, I have one question.  Is adding a web.config file intended to enable multi-file upload?  That didn't work for me, however I was able to upload a webp file using the single file uploaded and open the webp file using it's url as you described.  I was also unaware of the 'newui' - much improved

Comment: `Is adding a web.config file intended to enable multi-file upload?` Even I need to check that, I provided the link for your ask to enable `Webp`  in Azure App.

Comment: The `web.config` file settings allows you to enable `Webp` option, then the first option has to work to upload files.